# Sitecore recommends 250GB for the webserver, is this too much?

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore 6.5 Tuning up guide, http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/cms_tuning_guide_sc60-65-a4.pdf
Sitecore recommends the following for the Content Delivery Environment (web server):

- 8 GB RAM
- 250 GB disk

Why do we need 250GB for the web server, when the database is on a separate server?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for you to ask directly to Sitecore Support @ http://support.sitecore.net since the answer may be subjective and they can provide their reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a "standard" Sitecore implementation, the heavy variables when it comes to disk space usage on a content delivery server are Lucene indexes and the media cache (/App_Data/MediaCache). If you have many large Lucene indexes, they will subsequently require adequate disk space. The media cache is probably where you'll see the most disk usage, however, as media assets are cached to disk - after being retrieved from the database - in order to improve media retrieval performance.

You may also see significant growth in the "data" folder for your implementation - as logs and counter dumps can start to eat up space if your cleanup processes aren't keeping up.

As always, the guidelines provided by Sitecore are meant to provide you with a starting point. Due diligence and planning is always necessary when it comes to server resource allocation, infrastructure architecture, capacity planning.

Comment: Also don't forget about storing media items on disk (if applicable in the situation).

Comment: It depends strongly on your implementation and is indeed very subjective.